# Go to previous view if no items in UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a `Tab Bar Controller` with `UITableView` inside. When an item is selected from the table, it pushes another `View` with a `UITableView`. What I want to achieve is when the second View has 0 rows (all rows deleted) to simulate the `backBarButton` behavior - to go to the previous view (the one with the `Tab Bar Controller`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `-viewDidAppear`:

```
if ([yourContentArray count] == 0) {    // Or other way to check if there are 0 rows
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If you want to go back once several rows have been deleted, you could put it into the Delegate, too:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        if ([yourContentArray count] == 0) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your view Hierarchy like

```
UITabBarViewController
|--UINavigationController
   |--UITableViewController1
   |--UITableViewController2
```

If yes, then you should be able to `popViewControllerAnimated:` on the navigation controller.

Now I really, I mean really, don't advice to do that since it will create a very strange feeling for your user. If there is nothing to show, just don't let the user believe there is. Hide the mark for that row in the first tableView.

Comment: Actually it is only UITabBarViewController -> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController and what I try to achieve is just go back to the UITabBarViewController without pressing the "Back" button, but simulating its behavior in the code.

Comment: From your description, it totally isn't :). If you have a TabBar with a TableView and if you display another TableView if you tap an item, then VdesmedT is right.

Comment: How come you have a back button is there is only one viewController in the navigation stack ?

Comment: Actually yes, you are right, my mistake. I want to apologize as I am new to the whole iPhone stuff. Thanks very much for the help.